# Login button does not work for firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm a newbie at firebase.

I'm trying to code a simple login page where the user logs in and then is redirected to home.html.

This is my index page:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-action">Log in</button>
    <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-secondary">Sign Up</button>
    <button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action hide">Log out</button>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my app.js:

```
(function() {
  // Initialize Firebase
  const config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "fir-test-bb3bd.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fir-test-bb3bd.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fir-test-bb3bd",
    storageBucket: "fir-test-bb3bd.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "509522467811"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get elements
  const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
  const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
  const btnLogout = document.getElementById('btnLogout');

  // Add login event
  btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Get email and pass
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });

  // Handle Account Status
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      window.location = 'home.html'; //After successful login, user will be redirected to home.html

      // Add signup event
      btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
        // Get email and pass
        // TODO: CHECK FOR REAL EMAIL
        const email = txtEmail.value;
        const pass = txtPassword.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();

        // Sign in
        const promise = auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
      });

      // Add a realtime listener
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
          console.log(firebaseUser);
        } else {
          console.log('not logged in');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

When i go enter a valid username and password nothing happens, when I enter an invalid username and password nothing happens.  When I check the console logs there is absolutely nothing even though it should be stating what is happening.

Any idea?

Thank you again for any help.

UPDATE 1
This is the new login bit...still same problem

```
//Add login event
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
  //Get email and pass
  const email = txtEmail.value;
  const pass = txtPassword.value;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
{
promise.then(onResolve, onReject)
onResolve(e => console.log(e.message));
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
if(user) }{
window.location = 'home.html';
}});
```

Comment: please hide your api key

Comment: Try changing the `promise.catch` to `promise.then(onResolve, onReject)` and have an `onResolve` callback to check if it goes through. If it does, you can move your codes in `.onAuthStateChanged` into the `onResolve` callback

Comment: Updated original post with my updates...still the same problem.

Comment: Is all of this code necessary to reproduce the problem? For example, if you hard code all the values and remove input fields and buttons, do you get the same result? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there any log yet now with the `onResolve`?